# Test .NET Core WebAPI protected by Azure AD B2C with Swagger/Swashbuckle

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, swashbuckle

I've followed the instructions that I found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/isgupt/2017/09/04/swagger-authentication-against-azure-ad-b2c/), modifying them for ASP.NET Core.

Here is the modified configuration inside Startup.ConfigureServices(...):

[image: security definition code]

Here is the modified configuration inside Startup.Configure(...)

[image]

However, the problem is, when I deploy the WebAPI locally, swagger looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I can see that you use B2C_1BetaSignUp policy. I don't know if it is the root cause of your problem, but I think you should use SignIn policy.

Comment: Thanks for the response, It is a "SignIn or SignUp" policy.